# Laravel: how to write a route to get a hasMany relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-10

In Laravel, I have these Models that describe a day event where people participate in activities. Each event has many activities, but an activity belongs to only one event. I cannot manage to write a route that allows me to get the activities of a given event.

**Model Event**

```
namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Activity;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Event extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'events';
    protected $fillable = [
        'label',
        'date',
        'activities',
        'cassetteOperations',
        'bankOperations'
    ];

    /**
     * Get all of the event's activities.
    */
    public function activities(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Activity::class);
    }
}
```

**Model Activity**

```
namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\Participation;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough;

class Activity extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'label',
        'event_id',
        'memberPrice',
        'otherPrice',
        'memberEntryFee',
        'otherEntryFee',
        'type',
        'participations'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the participations for the activity
     */
    public function participations(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Participation::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the event associated with the activity
     */
    public function event(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Event::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the persons that participates to this activity
     *
     */
    public function participants(): HasManyThrough
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Person::class, Participation::class);
    }
}
```

In the **App/Http/Api/ActivityController** I have

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Activity;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\ActivityResource;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreActivityRequest;

class ActivityController extends Controller
{
    public function index($event_id)
    {
        return ActivityResource::collection(Activity::where('event_id', $event_id)->orderBy('id')->get());

    }

    public function store(StoreActivityRequest $request)
    {
        Activity::create($request->validated());
        //return only activities bound to the event
        return ActivityResource::collection(Activity::where('event_id', $request->event_id)->orderBy('id')->get());
    }

}
```

In **routes/api** I have

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::apiResource('person',PersonController::class)->middleware(['auth'])->middleware('App\Http\Middleware\Allowed');
Route::apiResource('event',EventController::class)->middleware(['auth'])->middleware('App\Http\Middleware\Allowed');

Route::get('activity/{event_id}',[ActivityController::class,'index'])->middleware(['auth'])->middleware('');
Route::apiResource('activity',ActivityController::class)->middleware(['auth'])->middleware('App\Http\Middleware\Allowed');
```

When in my vue project, I target the following

```
async apiFetchEventActivities(event_id) {
    try {
        await axios.get('sanctum/csrf-cookie')
        this.activityErrors = []
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/activity/' + event_id)
        this.activities = data.data

    } catch ({ response }) {
        this.activityErrors = [response.data.message, response.status]
        return ('failure')
    }
}
```

I get an error status 500  with "message": "Target class [] does not exist."

Is my route (the one before last in routes/api) incorrect, and why?
How should I write it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes/api.php` file, you have the following route:

```
Route::get('activity/{event_id}', [ActivityController::class, 'index'])
    ->middleware(['auth'])
    ->middleware('');
```

The problem seems to be with the second middleware method call, which is empty. If you don't have any specific middleware to apply, you can remove that line. also make sure you have imported the controller

you learn more about Laravel middlewares here https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have moved on now and if I remember well there was a discrepancy between the route get with parameter and the method index instead of show. Of course the empty middleware has nothing to do here.